# How do I force my Google home to download latest version of the local app

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I'm developing the smart device handler using Google Home Local SDK. 
How do I force device to reload and restart the app? (now I have to unplug the power cord, it does not looks good as it sparks)

also I have a couple of Google Home devices, how do I tell which of them should execute requests, is it possible to pin 'master' device?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm developing the smart device handler using Google Home Local SDK. How do I force device to reload and restart the app? (now I have to unplug the power cord, it does not looks good as it sparks)

Currently (during developer preview) you have to reboot the Home device to reload your local app. In an upcoming release, you will be able to refresh your app inside of Chrome DevTools but there is currently a known issue preventing this.

While unplugging your device may be the fastest way to reboot it, you can also reboot your device from within the Google Home app. Select the device, choose Settings, and you'll find **Reboot** in the overflow menu in the app toolbar.

> I have a couple of Google Home devices, how do I tell which of them should execute requests, is it possible to pin 'master' device?

Local execution currently relies on the Home Graph to determine whether to send a command locally. If the Home device and end device are configured in the same structure (and the device can be locally identified), then `EXECUTE` will be sent locally.

Comment: > If the Home device and end device are configured in the same room, then EXECUTE will be sent locally.

it's not the way how it is working for me currently, it seems like the last device restarted sends requests.


I have Nest hub in the bedroom and Google Home in the living room, a device is in the living room, and most of Execute requests comes from the Nest hub.

Comment: Edited as this part is no longer true, the devices simply have to be in the same structure (i.e. Home) in Home Graph. I've also filed an internal bug to update the documentation with more details about how a device is chosen as the local execution point.